# Groovy-Inserting a attribute at desired location

Tags: groovy

I have this xml data,

```
   <csv_data>
       <row Name="GokulaKrishnan" Age="23" Fees="12000" Department="CNW"/>
       <row Name="Sravan" Age="21" Fees="15000" Department="IT"/>
       <row Name="Bhanuchander" Age="23" Fees="23000" Department="WT"/>
       <row Name="Deepan" Age="25" Fees="25000" Department="VLSI"/>
   </csv_data>
```

I have coverted a csv file to above xml using groovy.Now I want to add another attribute called "City" for each person,how to add it after a name or age or Fees or at the End or Beginning in xml

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you post your code. anyhow, here is an example for adding an attribute to an xml node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7795634/947784

Comment: It does not matter for an xml parser where certain attribute is. It is treated as same irrespective of position.

Comment: Thankyou @Rao,whether altering the position of the attribute changes it reading from xml